# Gradle Internal slf4j is conflicting with my own slf4j dependency

Tags: java, gradle, slf4j

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/dev/gradle-2.9/lib/gradle-core-2.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/leo.j.lin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.5.11/14e29085f65a2e4e0f16e708f4135be122be562e/slf4j-simple-1.5.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
```

I have included these as my dependencies. When I run the build, the above error occurs. When I don't have the slf4j-simple dependency, the build will simply failed with error of "Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory"

```
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.11"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.5.11"
```

How do I fix this problem?

I have tried [Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440979/class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings-with-gradle), but it does not work for me.

EDIT:

This is the root project build.gradle

```
buildscript{

}

allprojects{

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies{
    compile "org.osgi:org.osgi.core:4.2.0"
    compile "org.osgi:org.osgi.compendium:4.2.0"
    compile "org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr.annotations:1.9.6"
    compile "biz.aQute:bndlib:1.50.0"
    compile "javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5"
    compile "javax.jcr:jcr:2.0"
    compile "org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.api:2.4.0"
    compile "org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.jcr.api:2.1.0"
    compile "junit:junit:4.8.2"
    compile "com.day.cq:cq-tagging:5.6.4"
    compile "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0.1"
    compile "com.day.commons.osgi.wrapper:com.day.commons.osgi.wrapper.commons-httpclient:3.1.0.018"
    compile "org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:2.2.9-R1523266"
    compile "org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr:1.6.0"
    compile "com.adobe.aem:aem-api:6.0.0.1"
    compile "org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.models.api:1.0.0"
    compile "javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1"
    compile "com.day.cq.wcm:cq-wcm-taglib:5.7.4"
    compile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"
    compile "junit-addons:junit-addons:1.4"
}
```

}

This is the subproject's build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/twcable/aem"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.twcable.gradle:gradle-plugin-cq-bundle:2.0.0"
        classpath "com.twcable.gradle:gradle-plugin-scr:1.0.1"

    }

}

apply plugin: "com.twcable.cq-bundle"
apply plugin: 'com.twcable.scr'

dependencies {
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0.1"
    compile "javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.2"
    compile "org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.commons.json:2.0.10"
    compile "com.day.cq:cq-commons:5.8.2"
    compile "org.json:json:20151123"
    compile "com.day.cq.wcm:cq-wcm-api:5.7.2"
    compile "com.day.cq:cq-tagging:5.6.4"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3"
    compile "com.adobe.granite:com.adobe.granite.fragment.xml:0.1.0"
    compile "commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.2"
    compile "commons-digester:commons-digester:2.1"
    compile "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2"
    compile "xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c"
    compile "com.day.cq:cq-search:5.6.4"
    compile "cglib:cglib:3.2.0"
    compile "org.apache:jackrabbit-ocm:2.0.0"
    compile "org.jibx:jibx-run:1.2.6"
    compile "com.day.cq.dam:cq-dam-api:5.6.6"
    compile "com.adobe.granite:com.adobe.granite.replication.core:5.5.38"
    compile "com.day.cq.workflow:cq-workflow-api:5.6.2"
    compile "org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.commons.osgi:2.2.2"
    compile "com.day.cq.dam:cq-dam-commons:5.8.2"
    compile "com.day.commons:day-commons-gfx:2.1.8"
    compile "org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.commons.mime:2.1.8"
}
```

The error is from executing the task from this plugin :

```
apply plugin: 'com.twcable.scr'
```

The plugin is on github: https://github.com/TWCable/gradle-plugin-scr

Comment: Gradle shouldn't be including its own dependencies into your project. Can you provide the relevant parts of the `build.gradle`?

Comment: @thatJavaNerd My build.gradle is empty except for the dependencies. I haven not added any custom code to it. It seems like Gradle adds the slf4j to the classpath, because one of the binding it finds is from the Gradle installation. Is it not?

Comment: @thatJavaNerd The weird thing is if I don't add my own slf4j-simple, it simply cannot find any binding, why doesn't it just use the "internal" one.

Comment: please show your full build.gradle

Comment: @RaGe Edited on the question.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue filed in the plugin issue-tracker for discussion: https://github.com/TWCable/gradle-plugin-scr/issues/1